# Is there any reason why I shouldn't use function objects instead of functions?

Tags: c++, function, functor

I've been trying to teach myself how to program by working through the book ***Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++ by Bjarne Stroustrup*** and I recently learned about function objects, the way it was described in the book it seems like I shouldn't ever use regular functions and should always use function objects instead, even if I don't need a state for the function. I couldn't find anything on this site or using goolge to check if I should be using them that way or not. Is it wrong? Are there any down sides to using them? Thank you in advance for helping.

Comment: stack overflow is for specific questions with clear objective answers.  Your question would be better on programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: @xaxxon oh okay, I didn't know it was that unclear, I was just hoping to find out if I was developing a bad habit by making all my functions into function objects.

Comment: First and one of the most importaing disadvantages is that the function objects require a plenty of code to work propely. You need to overload `operator()`, you also usually need to make a private destructor (as for any other singleton)... (Also, I personally think that the question is ok for this site.)

Comment: @MattC: Also, if you're going to ask on Prog.SE, you need to explain in more detail what the book says and why you feel that it led you to that conclusion.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Private destructor? Why? A struct with a single function will do the trick nicely.

Comment: @MattC best practices are off topic for stack overflow.  That is why your question is about to be closed.     "Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise."

Comment: @AlanStokes To prevent someone from creating extra instances of it? But I agree, it might be a redundant measure.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Functors should be cheap to construct; they don't need to be singletons.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Redundant implies that it is doing something useful that is already achieved in some other way. I can't see any reason that would be useful, and in fact have never seen anyone do it.